How to avoid burp suite from altering input dropdown values in java
We have an application which was tested from Burp suite, by intercepting and altering the values of the dropdown data in our application. Those fields are disabled when view through browser, but able to alter the data by intercepting and forwarding it through burp suite. Is there a way to avoid/control altering the data from my application either in json, controller, view or any other option?

Looks like you have not understood how security in web apps works. The client can always do modify anything. It is up to you on server side to check the incoming data if it is valid data by checking all the restrictions and rules on server side. Do never every rely on client side filter or restrictions.
